# how to pass a js value into the django url template tag

Tags: javascript, django

```
var c = "url chatloadchannel=" + String(channel)
fetch('% ' + c + ' %}')
```

how to pass this js value to the django

Answer (score 0):

You will get Js value after the django-templating-engine has rendered everything. So there is no point in passing js value to the django url template tag as it will not going to be rendered.
As an alternative you can use ajax.